# Excel COUNT slow when data sheet rebuilt

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working with an Excel add-in that deletes and recreates a data sheet when you refresh with data from a live database, in such a way that references to the data sheet do not get broken. I am using the formula COUNT('DataSheet'!A:A) to count how many rows of data there are minus the column header row. If the data is not refreshed will recalculates almost instantly, but when the data is refreshed using the add in the count slowly increases until the formula has finished calculating. I need to use other similar formulas which are slowing down the workbook significantly.

I can think of workarounds, but I need to know what is causing the difference in behavior when COUNT recalculates normally, and recalculates when the data is refreshed. At the moment the data is the same number of rows before and after refresh and the formatted range is not longer than the data.

Edit: I am wondering if this is something to do with the way excel handles which cells are active/filled in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome @TheGreatO96.

Try using COUNTA() instead of COUNT(), but I almost doubt that will help too much. I suspect you have a few things to optimise in your add-in. A database refresh is a volatile action, and it will trigger recalculations not normally triggered without the refresh. If you use any volatile functions such as OFFSET, INDIRECT, NOW  or even **conditional formatting**, things will crawl to a halt in a large workbook. The fact that you can see the value of COUNT(...) update in a single cell could point to significant delays in your macro. You could try adjusting a few things in your code:

- Start your macro with disabling recalculation. Run rest of code. Switch recalc back on.
- Start your macro with disabling screen updates. Run rest of code. Switch screen updates on.
- Start your macro with disabling events. Run rest of code. Switch events back on.

Ps. I once increased my macro execution speed by almost 2 orders of magnitude by just getting rid of OFFSET functions in favour of relative named ranges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mobus. The add-in certainly needs some work. A few things I should clarify - I am not using any macros, just a sheet for the data and a sheet with a count function gives this result. The database is a cloud application totally separate to the excel workbook. The add in fetches data from the database and makes use of the excel JavaScript API to 1) check if there is currently a sheet called “DBD-XYZ” and if so delete it. 2) create a sheet called “DBD-XYZ” containing the data fetched from the database.

Comment: Is it your add-in or third-party? Can you edit the javascript code? My answer doesn't really change though. Macro in this sense can be any code that interacts with cells, whether its recorded macro, VBA sub or UDF or javascript.

Comment: Also, you may want to try not writing to individual cells in a for loop, but rather block write an array of data one shot into the sheet.

Comment: Thank you Mobus you're an absolute star. I didn't understand what you meant before but you're completely right and that fixes everything. The JavaScript reads lines in iteratively but didn't switch off calculation or screen updates, so that counting up behavior was the COUNT re-counting for every line of data that was imported. All working beautifully now :)

Comment: Yay, glad to help. Kindly checkmark your question as answered.